Is there any technique that I can use to achieve the required computation without reading all 10 million rows?
I have a data file from a Monte Carlo simulation of fifteen protein chains. The file contains 10 million r_end_to_end 3D vectors as rows and 3 x 15 = 45 columns.
My task is to find the exact row where the simulation stabilized. In other words, I need to find autocorrelation time. In other words, I need to find the Tau0 time.
Now, the problem is that the data file is huge.
So, reading the entire 10 million rows is not practical for frequent testing, plot generation, curve-fitting, etc.
Is there any technique that I can use to achieve the required computation without reading all 10 million rows?

I don't think we can help without seeing an example input and the expected output. Of course I understand you can't show us 10 million lines, but could you give a toy example so we can understand the kind of data you are working with? And how slow? I made a toy example file with 10 million rows and 45 columns with perl -le 'for my $i (1..10000000){ print join("\t", (1..45));  }' > file. A simple operation (awk '($2 > $3){k++}' file) on the resulting 1.2G file only took ~1 second. Can you explain the kind of operations you will be running?

For the frequent data access stay away from CSV/TSV text formats and switch to i.e parquet or numpy arrays.
